# using eval to convert string into hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, eval

I have string like this

```
a="{\"company\"=>\"khkhkh\", \"email\"=>\"hjkh@hkkj.kjh\",\"address\"=>\"yiyiyu\", \"date\"=>Mon, 28 Apr 2014 13:14:10 BST +01:00}"
```

but i have made a mistake when generating this string. that is, i appended the date without converting to string. So now if i try to get back this into a hash using  **eval(a)** . This throws a error, with is acceptable.

```
SyntaxError: (eval):1: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting => ....
```

Is there any way to get that hash back, since iam in a situation that i cant regenerate this string.

Any help would be highly appreciable. 
Thanks.

Comment: what is the problem with adding quotes manually?

Comment: Actually there is problem in data, \"date\"=>Mon, 28 Apr 2014 13:14:10 BST +01:00. Date also should be in "" (double commas), after that use eval

Comment: a="{\"company\"=>\"khkhkh\", \"email\"=>\"hjkh@hkkj.kjh\",\"address\"=>\"yiyiyu\", \"date\"=>'Mon, 28 Apr 2014 13:14:10 BST +01:00'}"

Comment: eval(a)
=> {"company"=>"khkhkh", "email"=>"hjkh@hkkj.kjh", "address"=>"yiyiyu", "date"=>"Mon, 28 Apr 2014 13:14:10 BST +01:00"}

Comment: @gasanov this string i have saved this generated string in more than 2.5 lakhs of rows in rails db. so changing that is a difficult process

Comment: @sajjad  that is my question bro.. I have make it wrong, is there any way to extract the hash back, without changing the entire generation process.

Comment: You can write a regex substitution to do it as others have said. The bigger point is that using eval to create a hash like this is taking a huge security risk. Unless this is totally internal and throw-away code, you should be using JSON or yml or some other _data_ representation that can't be interpreted as arbitrary code. If you must have ruby hash syntax, then you should write a custom parser that can't run arbitrary code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your immediate predicament:

```
a.gsub(/\"date\"\s*=>(.*?)(\}|,\s*\")/, '"date"=>"\1"\2')
```

This should work even if the date is not the last entry of the hash.

For the next time around: It is *really* not a good idea to serialize data by manually turning them into code that you `eval` later. 
In most cases your best bet is probably to just generate JSON and parse that later. Using a proper JSON serializer/generator will also make sure your data is syntactically correct.

Comment: Thanks. That worked for me.. Yeah you are right.. but this i did when i didn't know much about JSON formatting.. From now onwards, i might choose the JSON way.. :)

Answer (score 1):

If the date is always last you could go with the straightforward approach:

```
date = a.gsub(/[\{\}]/, '').split('=>').last
a.gsub(date, "\"#{date}\"")
```

Will return

```
"{\"company\"=>\"khkhkh\", \"email\"=>\"hjkh@hkkj.kjh\",\"address\"=>\"yiyiyu\", \"date\"=>\"Mon, 28 Apr 2014 13:14:10 BST +01:00\"}"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple dates, try to replace them with quoted dates by regexp:

```
wrong_data = "" # your string
correct_data = wrong_data.gsub(/(\w{3}, \d{2} \w{3} \d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} \w{3} \+\d{2}:\d{2})/, '"\1"')
eval(correct_data)
```

PS. As @Gene truly noticed, you should avoid using `eval` in your code.